# Upgraded to Vue 2.7 and now getting a bunch of warnings: [Vue warn]: Vue 2 does not support readonly arrays

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

**Background**

I recently upgraded from Vue v2.6.14 to Vue 2.7 by following this guide: https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-2-7-naruto.html.

I made some changes (e.g., removing `@vue/composition-api` and `vue-template-compiler`, upgrading to `vuex-composition-helpers@next`, etc.).

**Problem**

The application loads for the most part, but now I get a ton of console errors:

`[Vue warn]: Vue 2 does not support readonly arrays.`

It looks like even just `console.log(workspaces.value);` (see code below) raises the warning.

**Question**

How do I resolve this issue?

Thank you!

**Code**

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import {
    defineComponent,
    onMounted,
    computed,
  } from 'vue';
  import { createNamespacedHelpers } from 'vuex-composition-helpers';
  import {
    modules,
    actionTypes,
    getterTypes,
  } from '@/store/types';
  import _ from 'lodash';

  const workspaceModule = createNamespacedHelpers(modules.WORKSPACE_MODULE);

  export default defineComponent({
    setup() {
      const { newWorkspace, listWorkspaces } = workspaceModule.useActions([
        actionTypes.WorkspaceModule.NEW_WORKSPACE,
        actionTypes.WorkspaceModule.LIST_WORKSPACES,
      ]);
      const { workspaces } = workspaceModule.useGetters([
        getterTypes.WorkspaceModule.GET_WORKSPACES,
      ]);
      onMounted(async () => {
        await listWorkspaces({
          Archived: false,
          Removed: false,
        });
        console.log(workspaces.value);
      });
      return {
        /*
        workspacesSorted: computed(() => {
          return _.orderBy(workspaces.value, ['LastUpdated'], ['desc']);
        }),
        */
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

`src/store/modules/workspace/getters.ts`

```js
import { GetterTree } from 'vuex';
import { WorkspaceState } from './types';
import { RootState } from '../../types';
import { getterTypes } from '../../types';

export const getters: GetterTree<WorkspaceState, RootState> = {
  [getterTypes.WorkspaceModule.GET_WORKSPACES](context: WorkspaceState) {
    return context.Workspaces;
  },
  [getterTypes.WorkspaceModule.GET_ALL_WORKSPACES](context: WorkspaceState) {
    return context.AllWorkspaces;
  }
}
```

`src/store/modules/workspace/actions.ts`

```js
export const actions: ActionTree<WorkspaceState, RootState> = {
  async [actionTypes.WorkspaceModule.LIST_WORKSPACES]({ commit }, payload: ListWorkspace) {
    const wss = await list(payload.Archived, payload.Removed);
    wss.forEach((ws) => {
      ws.Archived = payload.Archived;
      ws.Removed = payload.Removed;
    });
    commit(mutationTypes.WorkspaceModule.SET_WORKSPACES, wss);
  },
};
```

`src/store/modules/workspace/actions.ts`

```js
export const mutations: MutationTree<WorkspaceState> = {
  [mutationTypes.WorkspaceModule.SET_WORKSPACES](ctx: WorkspaceState, wss: Workspace[]) {
    ctx.Workspaces = wss;
  },
};
```

`src/service/useWorkspace.ts`

```js
  const list = async(archived: boolean, removed: boolean) => {
    const res = await get<Workspace[], AxiosResponse<Workspace[]>>('/workspace/list', {
      params: {
        archived,
        removed,
      }
    });
    return success(res);
  };
```

When I call `store.state.WorkspaceModule.Workspaces` directly (either in the console or in computed), I get no errors:

```js
import { useStore } from '@/store';

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const store = useStore();
      onMounted(async () => {
        await listWorkspaces({
          Archived: false,
          Removed: false,
        });
        console.log(store.state.WorkspaceModule.Workspaces);
      });
      return {
        workspacesSorted: computed(() =>
          store.state.WorkspaceModule.Workspaces
        ),
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, which was simply to upgrade to `vuex-composition-helpers@1.2.0`, as described here: https://github.com/greenpress/vuex-composition-helpers.

Answer (score 1):

This might be because `workspaces` is based on a getter, which are read-only. As mentioned in the [blog you were referring](https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-2-7-naruto.html) to, readonly is not supported for arrays in Vue 2.7:

> readonly() does create a separate object, but it won't track newly added properties and **does not work on arrays**.

It was (partially) supported for arrays in the [Vue 2.6 Composition Api Plugin](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api#readonly) though:

> readonly() provides only type-level readonly check.

So that might be causing the error. If it is mandatory for you, you might need to upgrade to vue3, or stick with 2.6 for a while. The composition Api plugin is maintained until the end of this year...

A workaround may be to skip the getter and access the state directly, since it is a quite simple getter which only returns the current state of `Workspaces`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is nothing like `readonly(workspaces)` anywhere, so I am not sure where the error is coming from. Is there anything else that I can check?

Otherwise, I might have to downgrade to v2.6.14.

Comment: The getter is taking the data from `context.AllWorkspaces`. How is AllWorkspaces defined? Are you getting the data from a graphQL api?

Comment: Added some more code. Essentially, `LIST_WORKSPACES` calls `await list` (which gets the data from a PostgreSQL database) and then commits the mutation `SET_WORKSPACES`.

Comment: Now thinking of it, you cannot write to a getter, so they might be inherently read-only :-) Perhaps you could test this by skipping the getter and accessing the `AllWorkspaces` from vuex state directly to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Updated the above. When I call `store.state.WorkspaceModule.Workspaces` directly, I get no errors. Ideas?

Comment: Yeah, I think that the getters are read-only and that this is not working on arrays in Vue 2.7 with the composition API. Since your getter is quite simple, only returning the actual state, as a work around I would skip the getter and access the state directly. I think a computed property will not work either. But you could try that. When upgrading to vue3 you can put it back the way it was.

Comment: Thanks, Gabe. Just trying to understand why readonly would be an issue. The getter is literally just returning the state. Computed with `store.state.WorkspaceModule.Workspaces` works fine also. Refactoring the entire application to access the state directly each time would be nontrivial, and there may be more complicated getters. It will be a while before we can upgrade to Vue 3 given some other dependencies that are stuck on Vue 2.

Comment: Yeah, I don’t know exactly why, but it has something to do with the reactivity overhaul in Vue3/composition api I presume. And that the vue developers could not make 2.7 fully compatible within a reasonable amount of effort. I understand that it might have quite some impact if it is a large application. These are the less funny things about web development, I guess.

Comment: you are using  `vuex-composition-helpers@next` it seems it's not compatible with Vue 2.7, if you can refactor this without this helper, it will probably be working fine